# ¿Como puedo hacer un ejecutable para windows 10 de python junto a mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

No puedo encontrar la menera de crear un ejecutable junto a mysql tengo la conexion hecha pero a la hora de crear el ejecutable no se como puedo hacer para que funcione mi base de datos...

Aqui esta la conexion:

```py
class Registro_datos():

    def __init__(self):
        self.conexion = mysql.connector.connect( host='localhost',
                                            database ='base_datos',
                                            user = 'root',
                                            password ='')



    def inserta_producto(self,codigo, nombre, modelo, precio, cantidad):
        cur = self.conexion.cursor()
        sql='''INSERT INTO productos (CODIGO, NOMBRE, MODELO, PRECIO, CANTIDAD) 
        VALUES('{}', '{}','{}', '{}','{}')'''.format(codigo, nombre, modelo, precio, cantidad)
        cur.execute(sql)
        self.conexion.commit()
        cur.close()


    def editar_datos(self, codigo, nombre, modelo, precio, cantidad):
        cur = self.conexion.cursor()
        sql = '''UPDATE productos (CODIGO, NOMBRE, MODELO, PRECIO, CANTIDAD) 
         VALUES('{}', '{}','{}', '{}','{}')'''.format(codigo, nombre, modelo, precio, cantidad)
        cur.execute(sql)
        self.conexion.commit()
        cur.close()


    def mostrar_productos(self):
        cursor = self.conexion.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM productos "
        cursor.execute(sql)
        registro = cursor.fetchall()
        return registro

    def busca_producto(self, nombre_producto):
        cur = self.conexion.cursor()
        sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE NOMBRE = {}".format(nombre_producto)
        cur.execute(sql)
        nombreX = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return nombreX

    def elimina_productos(self,nombre):
        cur = self.conexion.cursor()
        sql='''DELETE FROM productos WHERE NOMBRE = {}'''.format(nombre)
        cur.execute(sql)
        self.conexion.commit()
        cur.close()
```

¿Sera quee se crea de una manera diferente? gracias si me pueden ayudar se los agradeceria,
PD: A la hora de crear el instalador se cierra inmediatamente y no se mucho pero seguro es lo del a base de datos...

Comment: como creas el ejecutable?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vr9vl0qlggE aqui tome la idea

Comment: Todo lo que sea relevante debe ser agregado aquí en la pregunta